# Textview size differs for different mobiles

Tags: android, xml, textview

I am having 2 `Textview` one below first. It looks perfect on some mobile phones but on some mobiles its size gets changed, it is not covering the screen properly.

Below are my `Textview` one with **580dp** and another with **30dp**.

I can't make them match parents otherwise they will overlap each other.

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/page_data"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="580dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
            android:gravity="start|top"
            android:padding="15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/page_no_back"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Page No" />
```

Comment: What is the parent layout ??

Comment: Don't use absolute dimensions. Instead, use a `ConstraintLayout`, and define the relationships between your views as constraints. That way, your views can scale and adapt to whatever screen size they are on

Comment: You need to use Dimens for that.

Comment: What is your expected result? Can you show an image?

Comment: As told by PPartisan you can use constraint layout to scale for every screen. But if you want to show without the constraint layout, you can do it with the screen's ratio separately for hdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi,xxhdpi etc., @Ajinkya.

Comment: use android:layout_height="0dp" and android:layout_weight="1" for page_data id

Comment: Use linear layout with weight, make the height 0 for both the TextViews, make linear layout weight sum 61 (which is the equivalent of 580+30dp) give the first textView's layout_weight 58 and the second one a 3.

Comment: As Brahma Datta  says you nee dhdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi,xxhdpi etc. this will have in dimens file then you can add that in xml file

Comment: i have uploaded my xml file here i have set constraint layout but i am not able to set constraints. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dq8c_v70fFH5uzImWoT51cxSGAHKj-DN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overcome this problem by using `ConstraintLayout` as parent of the view and set `constraints` between views to define relationship. Check below layout as for example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#d3d3d3"
    tools:context=".Create">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="30dp"
        app:cardElevation="0dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/page_data"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/page_no_back"
                android:gravity="start|top"
                android:padding="15dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/page_no_back"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Page No" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202407/discussion-on-answer-by-md-asaduzzaman-textview-size-differs-for-different-mobi).

Answer (score 0):

I have edited the XML provided by you. Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    tools:context=".Create">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        app:cardCornerRadius="30dp"
        app:cardElevation="0dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/page_data"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="58"
                android:gravity="start|top"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/page_no_back"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Page No" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi Sandip, i have added  ***textView1.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());*** and also tried ***scrollview*** to scroll the text but the problem is other functionality gets disabled. like i have implemented long press on page and edit text. but when i put  ***textView1.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());*** or ***scrollview*** text is scrolling but long press is getting disabled. can you help on this.

Comment: Please take from here ... https://drive.google.com/open?id=11uce2rAKAuWxLspt0gjqdWLtwHR-k3SG

Comment: in above code i have implemented *** contextMenu.add(this.getAdapterPosition(),this.getAdapterPosition(),0,"Edit");*** so that when we long press it will give edit option. is i will put scollview nothing is happening when i pressed on page. if i remove scrollview popup is coming on long press

Comment: Normally Android uses a long press to begin a drag in cases like these since it helps disambiguate when the user intends to longPress an item vs. scroll the item's container. But if you have an unambiguous signal when the user begins longpress an item, try 'getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)' from the view when you know the user is beginning a press. This will prevent the ScrollView from intercepting touch events until the end of the current gesture. Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewParent.html#requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent%28boolean%29

Comment: Hi Sandip, where i have to add this line in my code ?

Comment: Place it in the block where you have written the code for long press

Comment: what we have to put instead of getparent() it is not taking getparent() i am getting cannot resolve method getparent()

Comment: Try to use view.getparent().

Comment: i am getting error : ***java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void android.view.ViewParent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean)' on a null object reference***

Comment: can you please show me the code so that i can help you in better way.

Comment: i have added code to below url  with name ***PagesAdapter_updated.java***  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TIPguBi0ZGsTT73NOwBvudkz12SLCKTr

Comment: please check public ***PagesViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)*** method

Comment: Refer this Link : https://medium.com/@harivigneshjayapalan/android-recyclerview-implementing-single-item-click-and-long-press-part-ii-b43ef8cb6ad8 , Then inside recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener you will find onLongClick

Comment: i think this link not explains the scrolling with long press. its only saying how to implement long press and single click. which i already implemented.